# SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

can anyone help me?
when i try to register a new admin, system show me an error: SQLSTATE[21S01]
I got the following code from similar question but it didn't solve the question

this is my class.admin.php, contain my function for register a new admin

```
public function registro_admin($auser, $aemail, $apass, $adep, $aname, $alast, $agender, $amatricula){
  try{
    $new_password = password_hash($apass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Admin(admin_user,
    admin_email,
    admin_password,
    admin_departamento,
    admin_name,
    admin_lastname,
    admin_matricula)
    VALUES(:auser, :aemail, :apass, :adep, :aname, :alast, :agender, :amatricula)");
    $stmt->bindparam(":auser", $auser);
    $stmt->bindparam(":aemail", $aemail);
    $stmt->bindparam(":apass", $apass);
    $stmt->bindparam(":adep", $adep);
    $stmt->bindparam(":aname", $aname);
    $stmt->bindparam(":alast", $alast);
    $stmt->bindparam(":agender", $agender);
    $stmt->bindparam(":amatricula", $amatricula);
    #$stmt->bindparam(":apic", $apic);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
  }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

this is my admin-register.php  this contain my html form and php code validation

```
  else if(strlen($apass) < 6){
  echo '<script>alert("Password must be contain more than 6 characters");</script>';
}else{
  try{
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT admin_user, admin_email FROM Admin WHERE admin_user=:auser OR admin_email=:aemail");
    $stmt->execute(array(':auser'=>$auser, ':aemail'=>$aemail));
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($row['admin_user'] == $auser){
      echo '<script>alert("Lo sentimos, el usuario ya existe");</script>';
    }
    else if($row['admin_email'] == $aemail){
      echo '<script>alert("Lo sentimos, el correo ya existe");</script>';
    }else{
      if($admin->registro_admin($auser, $aemail, $apass, $adep, $aname, $alast, $agender, $amatricula)){
        echo '<script>alert("Administrador Agregado con Éxito");</script>';
      }
    }
  }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Please help :(

Comment: no code, no help, but the error is clear. you're inserting X columns, but have Y values specified. value counts and field counts MUST match. e.g. `insert into foo (x,y,z) values (1,2)` - where's 3?

Comment: In the future, embed the actual code, as a code block, within your question, rather than embedding screenshots (which are more difficult to view, and impossible to edit).

Answer (score 2):

You only have seven columns defined in your `INSERT INTO`.  You need to include the gender column there.

So include `admin_gender` under `admin_lastname`

Comment: Thanks! that is the error, many many thanks for your help! :')